# How to get ENS name from specific wallet address in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get ENS name from specific wallet address (for instance "0x08d816526bdc9d077dd685bd9fa49f58a5ab8e48"=>kiwi.eth).
I'm using React 17.0.2 version because I have to integrate a new page to the live website.
Anybody know about it please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Javascript web3 library such as [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--ens-methods) and simply use the `lookupAddress(address: string)` method.

example output:

```
await provider.lookupAddress("0x5555763613a12D8F3e73be831DFf8598089d3dCa");
// 'ricmoo.eth'
```